# How to ingest multiple record JSON array into SQL Server using PutDatabaseReader

Tags: apache-nifi

The problem is that I am not able to process a bunch of JSON-records which came as output of the `QueryCassandra` processor. I am able to process record by record using the `splitjson` processor before `PutDatabaseRecord`.

I am trying to use `Jsonpathreader` in `PutDatabaseRecord`. **How can I configure the `PutDatabaseRecord` processor or the `Jsonpathreader` in order to process all records of the JSON at once?

Comment: You did not describe what is the problem..

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edit your question, let me know whether I described your problem correctly.

Comment: yes that's correct